# check if file exists by taking input from a file

Tags: bash, if-statement

need a script that dose the following checks if files exists by read input from a file then compares them to the files listed in the directory if they don’t exists the script would report back which file dose not exists. I also need to format the output so that files are grouped in different groups, group A, B, and C and etc based on file name. I would like the output of that do not exists files to be sorted based on second number in the file name than group according. I understand some of the basics of bash scripting something along of the lines of a loop and if statements might do the trick. Below is what I have so far.  I don’t car so much about  the script reporting back the file exists I prefer to only know if the file is missing and is less than 3 days old.

- Group A

  ```
  Foo22000.tar.gz
  Foo22010.tar.gz
  ```
- Group B

  ```
  foo25000.tar.gz
  foo25100.tar.gz
  ```
- Group C

  ```
  foo26000.tar.gz
  ```

So I have a somewhat working solution only problem is if a file is missing it would be compared against the wrong file IE.   This won’t work obvious. Because the it would compare foo3 against foo4 since the foo3 did not exists How do I solve this problem?

`File list`
`/home/foo/foo1`
`/home/foo/foo2` 
`/home/foo/foo3`
`/home/foo/foo4`

`Report file`
`/home/foo/foo1`
`/home/foo/foo2`
`/home/foo/foo4`

`find ~/ -name “foo*” –mtime -3 print>report`
`Sort report –o report`
`while read comp1 <&3 && comp2 <&4`
 `do`
`if [[ $comp1 = comp2 ]] then` 
`echo “file found” >/dev/null`
`else`
`echo “$comp1 not found”`
`fi`
`done 3<report 4<list`

Comment: `need a script that ...` -- this isn't the best way to start a question.

Answer (score 1):

```
File=/home/foo 
filestr=find /home/foo  –name “foo*” –mtime -3 print
for FILE_IT in $(find /home/foo  –name “foo*”)
do
   fl_it_basename=$(basename $FILE_IT)
   grep ${fl_it_basename) $FICHIER_GROUP_A >/dev/null 2>&1
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]
   then
      /// File is not present    
   else
     /// File is present       
   fi
done
```

Comment: You want more precision to resolve your problem ?